# How to overlay on top of the Keyboard in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard, uiimageview, overlay

How do you overlay something, ie a UIImageView over the keyboard which pops up when editing a UITextFIeld?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch keyboard window using following code, if you put it into textFieldDidBeginEditing method:

```
UIWindow* keyboard = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: As fare as a I know it does, at least I had no problems.